# nodejs can't find global modules

Tags: node.js

I recently install `nodejs` in `linux`. and write a simple code:

```
var http = require('http');
var sleep = require('sleep');
...
```

i install `sleep` with this command:
`sudo npm install -g sleep`
But, when i run the program with:
`nodejs test.js`
I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sleep'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mlibre/tmp/test/nodejs/test.js:2:13)
    ...
```

### informations

```
node -v
v6.6.0
```

```
npm -v
3.10.3
```

```
npm -g ls | grep sleep
└─┬ sleep@4.0.0
```

Comment: replace nodejs test.js with node test.js. and link sleep with npm link sleep solve the problem

Comment: Global modules are not loaded. (For one thing, this helps avoid so-called dependency hell.) Install them locally instead.

Comment: use this command: `npm link sleep`